# white text on yellow background

Tags: color

I am using a circle label to display the number. Because of UIRequirment , background of label is yellow and text colour is white. Text is not clearly visible. How to standout the white colour on yellow background

Comment: Why is that a UI requirement? It won't be able to be improved without adding unnecessary visual noise, and it's up to you to challenge that decision.

Comment: Unfortunately requirement can not be change. How to fix this. I am a programmer.

Answer (score 3):

For this particular type of query, you should go to the graphic design forum.

But some of the ways to handle these kinds of situations, you can put thin liner border of any darker color or put shadow on the white text.

[image]